# Converting an Image to a HTML mail signature

Tags: html, css, outlook, outlook-2013

I took our signature desing and turned it to a HTML code with my amateurish skills.

But when i put it to outlook, it looks broken.

Can someone show me how to do it or directly fix my code?

```
<div style="float:left;" id="renlogo">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bs6yRbO.png">
</div>

<div style="float:left;" id="colorline">
  <div class="green" style="background-color: #67b32e;width: 4px; height: 52px;">
  </div>
  <div class="pink" style="background-color: #e61e47;width: 4px; height: 52px;">
  </div>
  <div class="blue" style="background-color: #51bec7;width: 4px; height: 52px;">
  </div>
  <div class="yellow" style="background-color: #fcd021;width: 4px; height: 52px;">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="card" style="float:left;margin-top:20px;margin-left:12px;">
  <div class="renname" style="font-size:20pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:700;">
    Burçak ÇELİK
  </div>
  <div class="rentitle" style="font-size:15pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
    Co-Founder & Managing Partner
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div>
    <div class="rengsm" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
      <span style="font-weight:700;">GSM:</span> +90 (533) 625 04 49
    </div>
    <div class="renemail" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
      <span style="font-weight:700;">E-mail:</span> burcak.celik@renunion.com
    </div>
    <div class="renwebsite" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
      <span style="font-weight:700;">Website:</span> http://renunion.com
    </div>
    <div class="renadress" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
      <span style="font-weight:700;">Adress:</span> Kadıköy - ISTANBUL
    </div>
  </div>
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m46zx0oc/

Comment: Make sure images are public ally accessible; open html in browser copy it and paste to textarea in email settings to set signature;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```html
<table>
  <tr>
  <td>
    <div id="renlogo">
      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bs6yRbO.png" width="159" height="208">
    </div>
  </td>
  <td>
      <table style="border: none;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;">
      <tr>
      <td class="green" style="background-color: #67b32e;width: 4px; height: 52px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="pink" style="background-color: #e61e47;width: 4px; height: 52px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="blue" style="background-color: #51bec7;width: 4px; height: 52px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td class="yellow" style="background-color: #fcd021;width: 4px; height: 52px;"></td>
      </tr>
      </table>
  </td>
  <td>
  <div id="card" style="margin-top:20px;margin-left:12px;">
    <div class="renname" style="font-size:20pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:700;">
      Burçak ÇELİK
    </div>
    <div class="rentitle" style="font-size:15pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
      Co-Founder & Managing Partner
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
      <div class="rengsm" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
        <span style="font-weight:700;">GSM:</span> +90 (533) 625 04 49
      </div>
      <div class="renemail" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
        <span style="font-weight:700;">E-mail:</span> burcak.celik@renunion.com
      </div>
      <div class="renwebsite" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
        <span style="font-weight:700;">Website:</span> http://renunion.com
      </div>
      <div class="renadress" style="font-size:14pt;font-family:Calibri;font-weight:200;">
        <span style="font-weight:700;">Adress:</span> Kadıköy - ISTANBUL
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Instead of using `float:left`, use `table` instead. Outlook does not really handle `float` pretty well. Note that I added an extra `<td></td>` to create extra margin, feel free to add more for extra spacing.

Edit: Fixed the vertical colorline in Outlook. Also used a table for this to make it.

Comment: Jelte, thanks for your help. This is really a big progress for me. But the part <div id="colorline"> is not showing in the result. It's the colored vertical line between logo and info. Any ideas about fixing it? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey Burcak, I updated the code. I tested it in Outlook and it looks fine now.